# How to pull a Docker image from an authenticated registry to a specific repository in ECR using Bamboo?

Tags: docker, bamboo, nexus3, amazon-ecr

I have a task that I need to pull a Docker image from authenticated custom registry (Nexus3) to a specific repository in ECR using Bamboo. Anyone has an idea how to do? What are the flows? I have already got AWS ECR variables injecting and repository creating in ECR worked. The rest of works I am looking for a way to pull the image to the right place in ECR. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. We need to tag the ECR repository url to the image after pulling it from Nexus3.